# How to make images appear and disappear in iOS apps?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make my app **show an image (PNG) in the middle of a screen when a button is pressed** and then make it **fade** out after a few seconds. How would I be able to do this? Also it is a small png so how can i just make it show in its original size rather then stretch it out to fit the whole screen? **Any tip, suggestion or answer is greatly appreciated!**

Also I am new to this site so could you please tip me or **help me improve this question** as some people think it is not complete. Thank you everyone for your generous answers! :)

Comment: Well, to make it show in the middle of the screen you *could* position a UIImageView there.  Making it fade would probably involve using the animation stuff, but I've never attempted this.

Comment: (Have you considered actually looking at the documentation for UIImageView and UIView?)

Comment: I have but it did not help me and confused me even more :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initialize an [`UIImageView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with an [`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
// Assuming MyImage.png is part of the project's resources.
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
// Add imageView to a parent view here.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f delay:3.0f options:0 
                 animations:^{imageView.alpha = 0.0;} 
                 completion:^{[imageView removeFromSuperview];}];
```

Comment: Consider next time just giving a few hints.

Comment: I'll give an answer here for the second part of the question (displaying the image in normal size), as this is the best answer. You should set the *contentMode* property of the UIImageView to *UIViewContentModeCenter*. You can do this by selecting the UIImageView in Interface Builder (or in your storyboard) and setting the property, or programmatically : **imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;**.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your quick and helpful answers! I really love stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"], nil]; 

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.75 target:self selector:@selector(crossfade) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    mainImageView.animationImages = animationArray;                
    mainImageView.animationDuration = 4.5; //mainImageView is instance of UIImageView
    mainImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [mainImageView startAnimating];

    CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    crossFade.autoreverses = YES;
    crossFade.repeatCount = 1;
    crossFade.duration = 1.0;
```

and the target method:

```
- (void) crossfade {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut]; // user dependent transition acn be set here
    mainImageView.alpha = !mainImageView.alpha;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Consider next time just giving a few hints.

Comment: Man you guys totally rock! Thanks a lot for your answers and yes next time I will write a more detailed question :) Sorry I'm new and learning about posting proper questions. Any suggestions on how I could have made this better?

Comment: Hey @AppleDelegate When i try to compile using your code I get this ‘mainImageView’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for showing image for the few seconds on button press:
in your button action add following code:

```
imageView.image=yourImage;
 [self performSelector:@selector(waitAndGo) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

here is the implementation for the waitAndGo:

```
-(void)waitAndGo
{
    imageView.hidden=YES;
}
```